# Component makes a GET request on mounted() and props response to child component. What happens if I type URL that goes straight to child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So imagine I have these 2 URLs:

```
example.com/Profile
example.com/Profile/City
```

When `example.com/Profile` is visited, I present component `Profile` and when `example.com/Profile/City` is visited, I present component `City`.

I need to make a GET request that returns information used in both components. Currently, I make that GET request in the mounted() lifecycle hook of both components but I have been wondering if I can do it once only in the parent Profile component and then just props it down to City so that I could get rid of 1 GET request.

However, I am not sure what would happen if a user straight up types `example.com/Profile/City`? Considering the GET request is executed on mounted() of the `Profile` component and we haven't mounted `Profile` since the user straight up typed the URL that leads to `City` component , will I have the response in the child component?

Comment: Why not just make the GET request in `City` Component. Anytime from any place `City` component is rendered, it will automatically get its data from API. So its independent of from where you landed on `City` component.

Comment: That is exactly how I am doing it right now, however, this way I make the same GET request twice, once in Profile component and once in City component. I'm just not quite clear if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering the GET request is executed on mounted() of the Profile component and we haven't mounted Profile since the user straight up typed the URL that leads to City component , will I have the response in the child component?

No, you won't. You will end up with no data.

> I have been wondering if I can do it once only in the parent Profile component and then just props it down to City so that I could get rid of 1 GET request.

Not really. However if you used a global state management solution like vuex, you could move the request and the data into this global state and trigger the vuex action for the request from both component's `mounted`.

Then you could implement logic in your vuex action that would skip the request if the data is already present (i.e. from having previously visited `/profile`). But in that case you should make sure to save some timestamp so you don't cache the data indefinitely.

If you expect the data to change frequently, I wouldn't cache it like that at all and rather do a duplicate request everytime to ensure the data is a fresh as possible.